# Can someone identify this port on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

[image]

I think this logo means it's related to a DisplayPort, and I'm guessing it's probably a Mini DisplayPort, but could someone confirm it for me? I just want to make sure I don't buy the wrong adapter. My goal is to connect an HDMI cord to my laptop and I need an adapter since it doesn't have an HDMI port at base, and I'm guessing this might work for the other end?

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop and where is the port located. Please [edit] the question and add this essential information. Note that your user manual will almost certainly tell you exactly what port this is.

Comment: Did you look at the computer documentation? There is always a top, back and sides view of all ports. You should get important information that way instead of from anyone who might answer

Comment: The logo is the DisplayPort logo. Yes, it's a miniDP port.

Comment: HDMI to DisplayPort conversion is one way you might want to do adequate research before you purchase anything

Answer (score 4):

This is a mini Display Port.

The logo over it indicates that, as does the size and shape.

Answer (score 0):

It's a **DisplayPort Dual Mode** (DP++) logo, which means it can be passively converted to both HDMI and DVI signals, as well as standard DisplayPort.

If you're searching for a cable, look for "mini dp++ to hdmi".

See [Wikipedia - DisplayPort dual-mode (DP++)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#DisplayPort_dual-mode_(DP++))